# Заблокировать скролл окна

Tags: jquery, javascript, прокрутка

На сайте есть модальное окно с инфой и в этом модальном окне есть скролл, дак вот, иногда бывает что скроллинг "соскакивает" на основной документ и прокручивает его за модальным окном, вместо того чтоб прокручивать контент в самом окне, а это не есть хорошо.

Скрыть основной скролл тоже не катит ибо чуть съезжает макет, некрасиво, у некоторых юзеров вообще может вызвать негодование. Я набросал решение, но работает оно в лисе, фигохром, от которого основная аудитория, выпендривается, в опере не тестил

```
var scrllTop = $('html, body').scrollTop();
$(window).on('scroll.confirm', function(){
  $(window).scrollTop(scrllTop);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Сказал же что не катит, у основного каркаса стоит margin: 0 auto; и если скрыть overflow то место которое он занимал освободиться, из-за чего весь контент чуть-чуть съедет. Мне как-то жаловались юзеры на это, создается ощущение будто что-то "сломалось", а что непонятно

Comment: [Как это сделано Вкотнтакте](http://hashcode.ru/questions/220308/html-margin-0-auto-и-полоса-прокрутки#220463). Выход:

а) фиксация размеров с помощью `javascript`

б) кастомный слайдер

Comment: Ничего не подходит, значит придется смирится)

Answer (score 1):

При открытии modal запишите куда-нить в $.data() например scrollTop для всех элементов которые не надо скроллить, 
повесьте на document ->  отслеживаемые элементы событие scroll и

```
if ($(e.target).is('.modal') && e.target!==this) setTimeout(function(){ $this.scrollTop($.data($this).scrollTop)
},0);
```

в общем что-то в этом духе, сделаете пример с modal, покажу.